# Is "Mary Queen of the Universe" a recognized title for the Virgin Mary in Catholicism?

Tags: catholicism, virgin-mary, church-local, mariology

There is a Catholic Church near where I lived called "**Mary Queen of the Universe**" [(Link)](http://maryqueenoftheuniverse.org/).

It seems from their website it's a shrine for Mary. The name of this does not make much sense to me if it is a Christian church.

How is she the Queen of the Universe? I have never seen this in the Bible (any translation). All I can think of is the marriage supper of the Lamb for all the believers in the end, not just Mary.

Where did they come up with this title?  Is the title "Queen of the Universe" something found in established Catholic teaching?  Also, if it is an established title, what does it mean?

Comment: When I was working at Disney, I visited.  It's just a regular old Catholic church

Comment: [Regina Coeli (Queen of Heaven)](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/12718b.htm) seems to be the traditional title for the Queesnship of Mary.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Mary is the Queen of Universe because Christ is the King of Universe.

To understand her Queenship, one must understand how who the Queen of the Davidic Kingdom in the Old Testament Jewish monarchy was. It was the Queen Mother. The Kings had many wives, none of whom could be called Queen. That honor was reserved for the mother of the King. We see this in the role Bathsheba played with respect to King Solomon and the occasions when the Queen Mother acted as regent on behalf of juvenile successors to the throne.

> When Bathsheba went to King Solomon to speak to him for Adonijah, the king stood up to meet her, bowed down to her and sat down on his throne. He had a **throne** brought for the king's mother, and she sat down at his right hand. - 1 Kings 2:19

Hence by Jewish tradition, the Jews expected the Mother of their King to be the titular Queen. The same holds true for the New Kingdom of God. If Jesus is King of this new Kingdom, then Mary should by tradition be his queen.

In Revelation 12, the Women *who brought forth a child, who was to rule all nations with a rod of iron: and her child was caught up unto God, and to his throne* was seen **crowned** with of twelve stars. This women is traditionally identified as Mary. And this image of Crown is held to be one of the evidence for her queenship.

Comment: This is a great answer thanks for using the Bible a a source. I have looked up several sources on Revelation 12 and they seem different than what you said, since Bible is not open to personal interpretation I'll have to really figure out what this 12:1 means.

Comment: @JREAM Regarding the Revelations passage quoted above, if the child is Jesus Christ, then the woman must be Mary. We know the child is Jesus Christ because of the reference to "rule with a rod of iron," which appears also in Psalm 2: 7-9: I will proclaim the LORD’s decree: He said to me, “You are my son; today I have become your father.  Ask me, and I will make the nations your inheritance, the ends of the earth your possession.  You will break them with a rod of iron ; you will dash them to pieces like pottery.”)

Answer (score 9):

The Wikipedia page about [the church](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basilica_of_Mary,_Queen_of_the_Universe#History) explains:

> The use of the title "Mary, Queen of the Universe" is drawn from section 59 of [*Lumen Gentium*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lumen_Gentium), the Dogmatic Constitution on the Church issued in 1964 by the [Second Vatican Council](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Vatican_Council), which stated: "Finally, the Immaculate Virgin, preserved free from all guilt of original sin, on the completion of her earthly sojourn, was taken up body and soul into heavenly glory, and exalted by the Lord as **Queen of the universe**, that she might be the more fully conformed to her Son, the Lord of lords and the conqueror of sin and death."<sup>[[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basilica_of_Mary,_Queen_of_the_Universe#cite_note-lumengentium59-1)</sup> This usage could reflect Orlando's connection to nearby [Cape Canaveral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cape_Canaveral), the liftoff point for America's manned space program, as spaceflight was likely the inspiration for the term. Cape Canaveral is part of the Diocese of Orlando.

Answer (score 4):

This is a traditional title of Mary in respect of her Assumption into Heaven. It does not imply that she is in any sense above, or even equal to, God. Here is one thing that the *Catechism of the Catholic Church* says about Mary in this regard:

> "Finally the Immaculate Virgin, preserved free from all stain of original sin, when the course of her earthly life was finished, was taken up body and soul into heavenly glory, and exalted by the Lord as Queen over all things, so that she might be the more fully conformed to her Son, the Lord of lords and conqueror of sin and death." The Assumption of the Blessed Virgin is a singular participation in her Son’s Resurrection and an anticipation of the resurrection of other Christians:
>
> > In giving birth you kept your virginity; in your Dormition you did not leave the world, O Mother of God, but were joined to the source of Life. You conceived the living God and, by your prayers, will deliver our souls from death.
>
> By her complete adherence to the Father’s will, to his Son’s redemptive work, and to every prompting of the Holy Spirit, the Virgin Mary is the Church’s model of faith and charity. Thus she is a "preeminent and... wholly unique member of the Church"; indeed, she is the "exemplary realization" (typus) of the Church.

(paragraphs 966–967)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't know about the Catechism, I read in also there it calls Mary a "mediatrix". This would seem to conflict with Jesus being the only mediator between man and God? Or is it because she is the only mediatrix between man and God? I would think the Bible would mention if Mary was in that position?

Comment: I was trying to put in a quote from the catechism about that, but it doesn't fit as a comment. Nor does it fit with my answer, which I think I'll rewrite. But essentially we believe Christ is the unique mddiator; Mary's position does not detract from this but flows from it. I'm sure there is already a question on the site about that.

Comment: I see, thanks for your reply :) I did read it through!

Answer (score 1):

Not to over simplify but isn't the mother of the "King" always a Queen?  God, master and creator of the universe, chose one woman in whom to sow his seed.  From this spiritual union came the incarnation of the God-man Jesus who is the King of kings.

Comment: No, not always.  Someone has to establish a dynasty, and the parents of that person were not king & queen.